# When is a "down" migration useful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-schema, database-migration, rails-migrations

**Short version:**

What's up with `down` migrations? In what scenario(s) would you need to use one?

**Long version:**

Many frameworks that support database schema versions (including, not limited to, Rails' "migrations") allow the developer to specify how data upgrades (an `up` operation) can be reversed (aka `down`), or even automatically generate a downgrade operation by analysing the code (as in Rails' `change` method).

Indeed, it seems extremely common to do so in all the Rails migration code I've come across, which makes me wonder if it's considered a best practice.

Personally, I've never needed to downgrade a database schema, and I can't imagine a reasonable scenario where I would want to, either in dev or production. My experience seems at odds with the prevalence of `down` migrations, so I'm guessing I'm missing something...

What are the most common scenarios where a `down` is useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you've pushed a new version to production and run the migrations, and some time later you find a bug that can't be solved immediately. Since you need to keep the production server running, you revert to a previous commit. However, this wouldn't revert the changes made to the database, which would result in errors. So you'd need a way to roll back the changes made to the database, and then revert to the older version. This situation may not arise too frequently, but it's important to have the mechanism for when it does.

In development, you might run some migrations and later decide that you want to change, add, or remove something. Having a way to undo them means you don't need to create a new migration for every small change.

Answer (score 4):

Two reasons from the practice:

- code refactoring on the development environment - we can revert
  database schema, refactor model & migration and then migrate up
  again,
- rollup previous application version after sending a "lemon" to
  the production.

Missing "down" migrations means, that we haven't migrations at all, and we are back in the early 90' reverting database from backup or painfully modify the table(s) believing, that everything should go well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding the development workflow, couldn't this be solved (more easily and reliably) by taking db backups before the change and restoring? Also, could you please elaborate on what you mean by "roll up" after sending a lemon?

Comment: Yes, you can take db backup and the restore on the development, but you have to remember about that, and IMO it is more laborious than simply migrate down. Lots of migrations are done by single `change` method, so it is not necessary to write separate `down` method. "Lemon" sent to production is a problematic code for which the only reasonable way is reverting to previous version - reverting from backup may be not a good choice because of data stored by users, "down" migration is more graceful, we lose only data related to new features (if any).

Answer (score -1):

So Basically Rails can detect inverse operation when you create migrations like

```
add_column => remove_column

create_table => drop_table
```

But for some kind of migrations where you can't really use change to downgrade db schema, for example if you want to change the precision of a decimal column, then it would not be possible to guess the original precision on rollback? So you need to define the down method in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't made myself clear, I'll edit the question. I understand the way down migrations work, I just don't understand why you would ever use one.

Comment: Thats what I have answered there with the scenario where you can use "down".

Comment: It sounds to me that you are saying "you use a schema downgrade when you need to downgrade your schema". What I am asking is why you need to downgrade in the first place? What real world scenario causes you to want/need to downgrade?